# Can't set ItemsSource property without TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datagrid, invocationtargetexception

I'm trying to show paths of files in a directory in DataGrid. To do this, for the past hour I've been trying to set ItemsSource property of a dataGrid, but whatever I do I keep getting TargetInvocationException. I tried to use differents types of collections, even tried using Listbox or ListView, but no use. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community RC. This is the error I'm getting:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<FileInfo> fileInfo = new List<FileInfo>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = textBox.Text;
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            fileInfo.Clear();
            foreach (string s in fileEntries)
                fileInfo.Add(new FileInfo() { Path = s });
            grid.ItemsSource = fileInfo;
        }
    }
}

public class FileInfo
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

WPF Code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid" Margin="5,30,5,5">
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event is probably raised before the elements are fully loaded or the references are still unset, hence the exceptions.

```
        private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            if (!grid.IsLoaded)
            return;
   //rest of your code
  }
```

Comment: Yes, the event was raised when textBox text was set, when grid was not yet loaded. I fixed the code and now it's working. Can't tell you how happy I am :)